# Filter logic problems jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm

I have divs that are being dynamically created that contain a variety of article information, most importantly being a unique list of tags for each div.

```
<div class="resultblock">
        <h3 id="sr-title"><a href="/Code/Details/2">Blog Post</a></h3>
        <p id="srdescription">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#39;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
        <p>
            Last Updated: 01/01/3001 00:00:00 <span class="resultright">
                Author: Kayra</span></p>
        <p>
            Project: Kayra <span class="resultright">CMS:
                Umbraco</span></p>
        <p class="tag">
            Tags:
<a href="/Code?SearchString=Web%20Forms">Web Forms</a>                     | 
<a href="/Code?SearchString=Blog">Blog</a>            </p>
    </div>
```

I also have a complete list of tags that are dynamically created to be used as buttons to filter through the divs. I would like them to toggle the divs on and off; so for example if a user clicked the Facebook button only Facebook divs would show, then if the user clicked on Facebook again it would display all the divs. I would also like the buttons to work cumulatively, so if a user clicked Facebook and MVC it would only show Facebook and MVC posts.

```
    <div id="tagbar">
        <input type="submit" value="Facebook" class="button" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="MVC" class="button" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Web Forms" class="button" /> <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Blog" class="button" /> <br />
    </div>
```

At the moment my jQuery code is producing some odd behavior. Clicking on one button causes the filter to work fine, but you cannot click it off and display all of the posts as before. Clicking on multiple buttons also works; sometimes clicking a button off will work, but this is not consistent, sometimes it will need to be clicked multiple times before it works.

I feel that there is something wrong with the logic of my code but cannot find any online resources that could help me. Sorry if my question is ambiguous but it's because I'm not exactly sure where the problem is as I have only just started to use jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var tags = new Array();

// Array Remove - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
Array.prototype.remove = function (from, to) {
    var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
    this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
    return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};

$("#tagbar .button").click(function () {
    var clickedTag = $(this).val(); //Gets the name of the button clicked

    if (tags.indexOf(clickedTag) !== -1) {
        tags.remove(tags.indexOf(clickedTag));
        console.log("unclick");
    }
    else {
        tags.push(clickedTag);
        console.log("click");
    }
    $(".resultblock").each(function () {
        var theBlock = $(this);
        i = 0;
        $(tags).each(function () {

            var targetTags = theBlock.find(".tag a").text();

            if (!theBlock.hasClass("show") && targetTags.indexOf(tags[i]) !== -1) {
                $(theBlock).show();
                $(theBlock).addClass("show");
            }
            else if (!theBlock.hasClass("show")) {
                $(theBlock).hide();
            };
            console.log(tags[i] + " is comparing to " + targetTags + " and resulting in " + (targetTags.indexOf(tags[i]) !== -1));
            i++;
        });
        if ($(theBlock).hasClass("show")) {
            $(theBlock).removeClass("show");
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Any errors on your JS console?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the issue, but your `i` isnt declared with `var` meaning its global so that could be producing some wierdness. Also you dont need to define `i` yourself you can get it from [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(".resultblock").each(function (i) {
    // now you can use i - this would replace your i=0; setup.
    // your logic as before      
});
```

Comment: Thank you for enlightening me on better practices :) However it doesn't seem to have effected the execution of my code in any noticeable way

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is due to the fact that when `tags` is empty the code inside `$(tags).each(...)` is not executed. You need to add additional code to clear the filter.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on("click",".button",function(e){
    if($("."+e.target.id).hasClass("active"))
    {    var i=0;
        $(".active").each(function(){i++;})
        if(i>1)
        { 
           $(".ondiv").hide();
          $(".ondiv").removeClass("active");
          $("."+e.target.id).addClass("active");
          $("."+e.target.id).show();

        }
        else
        {
         $(".ondiv").show();
         $(".ondiv").addClass("active");
        }
    }
    else
    {
      $(".ondiv").hide();
      $(".ondiv").removeClass("active");
      $("."+e.target.id).addClass("active");
      $("."+e.target.id).show();
    }

})

</script>



<div id="tagbar">
    <input type="button" value="Facebook" class="button "  id="Facebook"/> 
    <input type="button" value="Google" class="button "  id="Google"/> 
    <input type="button" value="youtube" class="button"  id="youtube"/>
    <input type="button" value="Jquery" class="button "  id="Jquery"/> 
</div>



<div class="Facebook ondiv" style="border:1px solid #000; width:300px; height:200px; float:left">
    <b style=" color:red; margin:100px;"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100009644795095">hi i am Facebook</a> </b>
</div>
    <div class="Google ondiv" style="border:1px solid #000; width:300px; height:200px; float:left">
    <b style=" color:black; margin:100px;"> hi i am Google </b>
</div>
    <div class="youtube ondiv" style="border:1px solid #000; width:300px; height:200px; float:left">
    <b style=" color:blue; margin:100px;"> hi i am youtube </b>
</div> 
    <div class="Jquery ondiv" style="border:1px solid #000; width:300px; height:200px; float:left">
    <b style=" color:green; margin:100px;"> hi i am Jquery </b>
</div>
```